# How to specify the constraint with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database, constraints

I have the following 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE BUBBLES_CSC (
CSC_ID integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
COUNTRY_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
STATE_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CITY_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CSC_ID,STATE_NAME,CITY_NAME),
INDEX(CSC_ID ,CITY_NAME,COUNTRY_NAME )
);

CREATE TABLE BUBBLES_REGION (
REGION_ID integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
REGION_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CSC_ID integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(REGION_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CSC_ID) REFERENCES BUBBLES_CSC(CSC_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
INDEX(REGION_ID ,REGION_NAME ,CSC_ID )
);

CREATE TABLE BUBBLES_HOTEL (
HOTEL_ID integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION varchar(255) DEFAULT "No description",
CSC_ID integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
REGION_ID integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(HOTEL_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CSC_ID) REFERENCES BUBBLES_CSC(CSC_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (REGION_ID) REFERENCES BUBBLES_REGION(REGION_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
INDEX(HOTEL_ID,NAME,CSC_ID,REGION_ID)
)CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

Now i know how to do a foreign key, But how to specify that the CSC_ID in BUBBLES_HOTEL should be same as the CSC_ID specified in BUBBLES_REGION for the row pointed to by REGION_ID in BUBBLES_HOTEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is not to have the column `CSC_ID` in `BUBBLES_HOTEL` at all. Each row in `BUBBLES_HOTEL` contains a link to a row in `BUBBLES_REGION`, which in turn contains a link to a row in `BUBBLES_CSC`. That's how you identify to which row in `BUBBLES_CSC` a given row in `BUBBLES_HOTEL` corresponds. Your current design is not normalised.

Having said that, you could achieve what you ask by replacing the two foreign keys on `BUBBLES_HOTEL` with just one:

```
FOREIGN KEY (CSC_ID, REGION_ID) REFERENCES BUBBLES_REGION (CSC_ID, REGION_ID)
```

Comment: I refer to the HOTEL tabel a lot and search a lot for the other 2 tables. If i make as you said a single foreign key relation will it make any difference to my query fetching capabilities and make it any slower while retrieving data for a single row in all the three table

Comment: You may wish to add an index on `BUBBLES_HOTEL` with `REGION_ID` as the first column (as it would no longer be implicitly indexed).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all three relations create one-to-one-to-one chain. If so, you should not have the CSC_ID column in BUBBLES_HOTEL, it is redundant: you always can get it via BUBBLES_REGION.

Comment: If i use HOTEL table to search a LOT then is having redundant table advantageous? Thats what was my thought. Cos i need table data from all the 3 tables many times while searching

Comment: It depends on the number of rows in your table HOTEL. If you are talking about tens or hundreds of entries, I doubt you need to worry about efficiency of SQL queries. On the other hand, if there are thousands of hotels, it could be wise to make one relation instead of three. But SQL optimization is way beyond my knowledge.

Comment: The number of hotels is in the order of 10000 But the other 2 tables are in the range between 100-999 ma be.